# Drupal 7: Help me to wrap my head around EVA/reverse node reference

Tags: views, nodes

What I wanna do shoult be quite easy but but till now I've been without luck. I've read different approaches but none of them worked for me.

Setting: Drupal7/Views 3.6/References/EVA

We have 2 node types: 
"article" (e. g. "How to sleep better" and "What your dreams mean")
"theme week" (e. g. "Sleep")

"theme week" has a node relationship field which points to the "article" node type (i. e. theme week "Sleep" has references to "How to sleep better" and "What your dreams mean").

Now I want to show that referenced articles in my "theme week" node which reffers them. I use EVA to attach a view to my "theme week" node.

Problem: I can't get to set up the view properly; my guess is that I'd use a reverse relationship to my reffering node "theme week", but till now I haven't been lucky with that.

Any advices (step-by-step) would be highly appreciated! Do I have to set up a contextual filter as well? Which fields/filters must use the relationship?

Thanks in advance to everyone
sp

Comment: Can you clarify or edit this: "Now I want to show that referenced articles in my "theme week" node which reffers them. I use EVA to attach a view to my "theme week" node."

Comment: Clarification: the "theme week" node should show a view with the "article" nodes which are chosen on creation of a "theme week" (via node reference).

Edit: I did it, here's how: i did NOT use the reverse reference, but a normal one. Here's how:

- I used a normal relationship to the node type "article"
- I did NOT set "require relationship"

Answer (score 1):

OK, i did it. Here's how:

**Node types:**
I've set up 2 node types "article" and "theme week".
"theme week" has a node reference field where nodes of the type "article" can be choosen.

**View:**
 - I've set up one "EVA" view (requires EVA) Under "advanced", I've
   selected the relationship to my "article" node type. 
 - I did NOT set "require relationship". 
 - Unter "contextual filter" I've set "Content: Nid", "Provide default value -> Content ID from URL".
 - I've set all my fields and filter criteria to use that relationship

**Display Suite/EVA:** - I've attached my View as a field in my "theme week" node type (requires Display Suite/DS).

Now when a "theme week" node is viewed, it shows the "article" nodes which have been referenced by "theme week".

I hope this might be useful to someone!